# string with space adds newline fputcsv php

Tags: php, fputcsv

I'm writing a tab delimited file and for strings that contain a space, I get a newline in the output file before and after the string.

Most likely it hicks on the string delimiter ( 0x00 ?).

```
$name='test123';

$file = fopen('upload/' . $name, "w+");

$row = array (123,456,789, "appels qewq",123);
        fputcsv($file, $row , "\t", "\n");
fclose($file);
```

This ouputs:

```
123<tab>456<tab>789<lf> 
appels qewq<lf>
<tab>123<lf>

<tab> being 0x09 <lf> = 0x0d.
```

How can I have this handle the string correclty.

Cheers,

Frank.

Comment: Ummm... you are passing `\n` as the string enclosure, forth argument!

Comment: oh no. I am.
Looking over the obvious. Thanks!